# What will cause XML deserialize exception?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

> In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx), it says that xml deserialization  is very **forgiving** if
> a deserialized XML document doesn't closely match up with the object.
> There is only a few error conditions lead to exceptions during the
> deserialization process. The most common ones are:
>
> 1. The name of the root element or its namespace did not match the expected name.
> 2. An enumerated data type presented an undefined value.
> 3. The document contained illegal XML.

### My question

I want to know what else situations will cause xml deserialization exception?

## My exploration

I figured out this might be true: if a value specified to an atomic element (the type of this element can't expand anymore), and the value can't implicitly convert from `string` to the type of the element (like `int`, `double` and etc), it will throw exception.

Example:
xml: `<Class1><X1>Foo</X1></Class1>`

class:

```
public class Class1 {
    public int X1;
}
```

Because the value in `xml` is `Foo`, and it can't convert `Foo` to a int, so exception will be thrown. But xml deserialization will forgive that:

1. Change the value `Foo` to `10` (any int value).
2. Change `public int X1` to `public Class2 X1`, `Class2` is a new class, XML will forgive it.

But these are all my guess :(

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: When a property doesn't match the schema requirements.